# Google barchart grouped and stacked

Tags: charts, google-visualization, bar-chart

elow you will find my grouped and stacked barchart, this works so far fine. But how can I add the information of the grouped value.

If I roll over each block I get the value of this block, but I need the cumulation of the blocks.

Example: Block1: 1.000 Block2: 1.500 Block3: 1.000 Block4: 2.000

If I roll over the third block the value must be 3.500.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript">

  google.load('visualization', '1.1', {'packages': ['bar']});

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);

function drawStuff() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', '');
    data.addColumn('number', 'level 1');
    data.addColumn('number', 'level 2');
    data.addColumn('number', 'level 3');
    data.addColumn('number', 'level 4'); 
    data.addColumn('number', 'current value');    
    data.addRows([
        ['Team1',  {!Team1_l1}, {!Team1_l2}, {!Team1_l3}, {!Team1_l4}, {!Team1_cv}],
        ['Team2',  {!Team2_l1}, {!Team2_l2}, {!Team2_l3}, {!Team2_l4}, {!Team2_cv}],
    ]);

    var options = {
        isStacked: true,
        width: 890,
        height: 500,
        backgroundColor: '#F8F8F8',

        chartArea: { backgroundColor: '#F8F8F8' },

        chart: {
            subtitle: 'current view of the incentive'
        },        
        vAxis: {
            format: 'decimal',
            viewWindow: {
                min: 0,
                max: 30000000
            }
        },       
        series: {
            4: { targetAxisIndex: 1 }, 
            5: { targetAxisIndex: 1 }
        }
    };
    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
}

</script>

<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

only way to change the tooltip is to provide a custom one using a [tooltip column role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#tooltiprole)

however, column roles are not support by *Material* charts ([along with many other options](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143))
`google.charts.Bar` --- `packages: ['bar']`

using a *Classic* chart is the only option...
`google.visualization.ColumnChart` --- `packages: ['corechart']`

---

to aggregate the values of each stack, provide a custom tooltip
use a [DataView](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataView) and the [setColumns()](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataView_setColumns) method to dynamically add columns for the tooltips

to use custom html tooltip, must set property --> `html: true` -- on the column,
and set chart option --> `tooltip: {isHtml: true}`

there is a minor bug with `DataView`, it does not respect column properties
must convert back to a `DataTable` before drawing --> `dataView.toDataTable()`

---

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', '');
  data.addColumn('number', 'level 1');
  data.addColumn('number', 'level 2');
  data.addColumn('number', 'level 3');
  data.addColumn('number', 'level 4');
  data.addColumn('number', 'current value');
  data.addRows([
    ['Team1',  1000, 1500, 1000, 2000, 1800],
    ['Team2',  2000, 2500, 2000, 3000, 2800]
  ]);

  var options = {
    isStacked: true,
    width: 890,
    height: 500,
    backgroundColor: '#F8F8F8',
    chartArea: {
      backgroundColor: '#F8F8F8'
    },
    chart: {
      subtitle: 'current view of the incentive'
    },
    colors: ['#2196f3', '#42a5f5', '#64b5f6', '#90caf9', '#bbdefb'],
    tooltip: {
      isHtml: true
    },
    vAxis: {
      format: 'decimal',
      viewWindow: {
        min: 0,
        max: 15000
      }
    }
  };

  // number formatter
  var formatNumber = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    pattern: options.vAxis.format
  });

  // build data view columns
  var viewColumns = [];
  for (var col = 0; col < data.getNumberOfColumns(); col++) {
    addColumn(col);
  }
  function addColumn(col) {
    // add data table column
    viewColumns.push(col);

    // add tooltip column
    if ((col > 0) && (col < (data.getNumberOfColumns() - 1))) {
      viewColumns.push({
        type: 'string',
        role: 'tooltip',
        calc: function (dt, row) {
          // calculate aggregate
          var aggregateValue = 0;
          for (var aggCol = 1; aggCol <= col; aggCol++) {
            aggregateValue += dt.getValue(row, aggCol);
          }

          // build custom tooltip
          var tooltip = '<div class="ggl-tooltip"><div><span>';
          tooltip += dt.getFormattedValue(row, 0) + '</span></div>';
          tooltip += '<div>' + dt.getColumnLabel(col) + ':&nbsp;';
          tooltip += '<span>' + formatNumber.formatValue(aggregateValue) + '</span></div></div>';

          return tooltip;
        },
        p: {html: true}
      });
    }
  }
  var dataView = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  dataView.setColumns(viewColumns);

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  // use data view to draw chart
  chart.draw(dataView.toDataTable(), options);
});
```

```css
.ggl-tooltip {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
}

.ggl-tooltip div {
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.ggl-tooltip span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

**note:** `jsapi` should no longer be used to load the charts library,
according to the release notes...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the `jsapi` loader is no longer being updated consistently. The last update, for security purposes, was with a pre-release of v45. Please use the new gstatic `loader.js` from now on.

this will only change the `load` statement, see above snippet...

Comment: Thanks for your response, but now all values are stacked, I need just the four values stacked and the fifth grouped.

Comment: do you have an idea?

Comment: Ok, that means we have no chance to show the tooltip and the grouped chart?

Comment: Ok, are there any other options instead of google graph.